# errors upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04 about Unknown Multi-Arch type for compiz, libkf5akonadisearch-bin packages

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, 16.04, multiarch

I'm trying to upgrade my 14.04 machine to 16.04 using `do-release-upgrade`. After downloading the package lists for wily, I see the following errors:

```
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libkf5akonadisearch-bin'
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-http-message-implementation
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-log-implementation
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libkf5akonadisearch-bin'
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

It then proceeds to abort the installation. The suggested run of `apt-get update` doesn't seem to do anything. Googling for the above error messages yielded others having similar problems when upgrading to other, previous releases, although I've not come across any apparent fixes. It's suggested that an `apt` upgrade could fix the problem, but I don't see a way to easily do that (it's up to date with the latest trusty package).

What should I do in order to upgrade directly to 16.04?

Comment: It looks like those three packages - `libkf5akonadisearch-bin`, `compiz-core`, `compiz-gnome` have broken meta data, though it's unclear whether that is so in the old ones or in the new ones. In case it's in the old packages, could you try removing the three temporarily and see if it helps?

Comment: Also, if it's 16.04 you want, that should be xenial, not wily.

Comment: Fwiw, this is not an issue with the installed packages; I get it too, and I don't have any of those packages installed.

Comment: Agreed with @Doug. None of these packages are installed for me, and I still get the error.  Totally stuck.

Comment: Isn't that os version very old?  Does your computer support a newer version?

Answer (score 16):

This is a bug in apt, and yes, the fix is to upgrade apt.

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and uncomment these lines:

```
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted
deb http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted
```

Now run `apt-get update` and you'll see the same errors about 'Unknown Multi-Arch type'.

Now upgrade apt:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade apt
```

Now run the release installer:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

:)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.  Tried several mirror variants and I always get "apt is already the newest version" and still the original show-stopping error described by OP.

Comment: @sstringer All I can suggest is make absolutely sure that you're updated the sources list and are pulling down the package list from the next major version (ie. Wily). `apt-get update` should show it downloading a whole pile of packages. ...sorry I can't be more help. This is a super frustrating bug I know. All I can say is: However you do it, you need to upgrade apt to get past the issue, it's the only solution I've ever found to this issue.

Comment: One has to ensure that no apt-pinning is in place.

Answer (score 4):

What seems to have worked for me was

```
apt-get -f install libc6
apt-get install --only-upgrade apt
```

Comment: I used this to help with w/ a Mint 17->18 upgrade.  These errors seem like false positives.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me :

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

I had segmentation faults errors during the install, so I cleared the archives again:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

And everything went fine.

Hope it'll help !

Answer (score 0):

I also get the "newest version" message, but according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1404783/comments/12

I added sources for vivid and vivid-updates to sources.list and installed the apt/vivid version.

```
sudo apt-get -t vivid install apt/vivid
```

Then I deleted vivid source from sources.list and apt-get update finished without any warning.

Comment: `apt-get` doesn't have a -t option.

Comment: It does actually, the -t flag is for --target-release.

Answer (score 0):

Almost had an answer.

I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Update and upgrade commands malfunctioned. I could not find a solution anywhere. The only thing that worked for me was:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

That seemed to upgrade me to Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic, though with some errors.