# sudo apt-get update get error in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04. When I give sudo apt-get update command it gives the following warning

> Fetched 4,156 kB in 33s (123 kB/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done
>
> W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
>
> W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
>
> W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
>
> W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
>
> W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

How can I solve this warning?

Comment: Those are warnings, not errors. Do you have any additional repositories enables besides the official Trusty ones?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760071/errors-upgrading-from-14-04-to-16-04-about-unknown-multi-arch-type-for-compiz-l

Answer (score 0):

My sticky small suggestion is that you may use Synaptic Package Manager for that. Open Synaptic Package Manager -click Settings-click Repositories-Software Sources-in the first tab tick all options including Source Code-Main Server.
Remaining all Tabs options you may ticked it out and click close option.
Now Click on Reload option. It will download repository first. When it completed you may choose your package which you want to download and install with Mark for Installation option.

If you are working with Proxy Server Internet then you need to specify the settings in Preferences option.