# I have an unknown error that says "E:The package libsdl-gfx 1.2-4 needs to be reinstalled but there is no archive for it."

Tags: package-management

It says it is a serious problem and I should report to developers. Please help!

```
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libxapian-dev'
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-dev'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-wayland'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-x11'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libkf5sysguard-dev'
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-http-message-implementation
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-log-implementation
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-seclib
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-sabre-http
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libxapian-dev'
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-dev'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-wayland'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'kwin-x11'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'libkf5sysguard-dev'
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-core'
W:Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package 'compiz-gnome'
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W:Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
W:You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E:The package libsdl-gfx1.2-4 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Comment: Your problem seems very similar to this:http://askubuntu.com/questions/760071/errors-upgrading-from-14-04-to-16-04-about-unknown-multi-arch-type-for-compiz-l, take a look at the answers