# cannot reinstall upstart

Tags: upstart

I followed a fix for another issue but now the reboot and shutdown executables are missing. I have tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall upstart
```

But I get this line at the end

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/upstart.postinst: 38: 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/upstart.postinst: telinit: not found
```

And the executables are still missing.

This is the output of /bin/sh -e -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/upstart.postinst

```
+ ischroot
+ initctl+ tr -d )
 version
+ awk {print $3}
+ UPSTART_VERSION_RUNNING=1.12.1
+ dpkg --compare-versions 1.12.1 ge 1.9
+ telinit u
/var/lib/dpkg/info/upstart.postinst: 38: 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/upstart.postinst: te           linit: not found
+ :
+ [  = configure ]
+ dpkg-maintscript-helper rm_conffile /etc/init/upstart-dbus-bridge.conf 
1.9.1-0           ubuntu4 --
dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: couldn't identify the package
```

ran sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd-sysv upstart
and got the following warning in the output

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
```

then had kernel panic when starting the machine including the line

```
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
```

managed to get to login by choosing 3.13.0.65 (upstart)

at login I am shown this message

```
[24.187631] system-logind[1553]: Failed to start user service, ignoring: Unknown unit: user@1000.service
```

I cannot connect remotely to the machine, nor to the plex server running on it

Comment: the previous issue was that I was getting these "Unknown Multi-Arch type 'no' for package ***" messages when trying to run apt-get update... and the new problem occurs since performing the solution posted in the top answer here... https://askubuntu.com/questions/760071/errors-upgrading-from-14-04-to-16-04-about-unknown-multi-arch-type-for-compiz-l

Comment: Could you [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/989807/edit) the output of `/bin/sh -e -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/upstart.postinst`

Comment: The answers in [Error “/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory” - but not Grub related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199164/error-run-lvm-lvmetad-socket-connect-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-but) may be useful for the new error. Could you add what release you are on.

Comment: Do you have a recent backup of the important files from this system? Do you have a liveusb? Is the important data encrypted?

Comment: The system is used to store all my media on plex. Files are on 4 drives in a raid5 array so I hope could all be recovered

Comment: I don't have a liveusb

Comment: Should I create and liveusb and do a completely fresh install?

Comment: If I were in your position I would use a liveusb to check that the raid data was fine and accessible. If so then a fresh install not touching the raid if possible.

Comment: I've done a fresh install and re-mounted the raid array no problem. Everything working fine now. Thanks for your help J

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need to reinstall `systemd-sysv` which provides `telinit`. Additional steps may be necessary if other errors are revealed, if so [update](https://askubuntu.com/posts/989807/edit) your question.
Run the following command to reinstall both:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd-sysv upstart
```

You can find what package supplies `telinit` by running `dpkg` with the search flag, see [How do I find the package that provides a file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/482/723193)

```
dpkg -S telinit
systemd-sysv: /sbin/telinit
systemd-sysv: /usr/share/man/man8/telinit.8.gz
upstart: /lib/sysvinit/telinit
```